How to dynamically set the database schema from a PowerBI embedded report?
I have a web application in which I have embedded a PowerBI report. My application is multitenant, which means each customer access their own database schema in the application's PostgreSQL database (customer1 has their data in database.tenant1_schema, cusomer2 has it in database.tenant2_schema and so on).
I would like to replicate this behavior in the embedded PowerBI report using direct query.  I would like to send the database schema corresponding to the user's session to the embedded PowerBI report through javascript, so it can run SQL queries using the received schema like this:
select id, description
from [@dbschema].products

I know how to send a filter through javascript when all customers shared the same database schema. I also know how to define a "dbschema" parameter in the report and use it to make a dynamic query. What I do not know is how to make the report to accept something coming from the javascript (e.g. a filter) as a value for "dbschema" parameter.
But now that each customer has their own PostgreSQL database schema I want to make it dynamic, so my customer in tenant1 can see data coming from tenant1_schema.products while other customer in tenant2 see their data coming from tenant2_schema.products.
As far as I know, parameters only work on PowerBI desktop and cannot be set dynamically for reports published to PowerBI online (which I need for my report is embedded to a web application).
How can I do that?
